# How to change the default font in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) how can I change the default font to use? Whenever I drag an item the default font is **Helvetica, 17**.

Answer (score 13):

The font defaults to whatever the last font set on a cell is. Change the font family and font size on a cell and that will become the default.

To clear default styling, ensure nothing is and click "clear default styling" in the right hand format panel.

[image: The diagram format panel in draw.io]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a shape with text formatted as you need, select "Set as Default Style".
Next element will have that style.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a a shape e.g. box which has the text font as You wish to be as a default font, then in the "format pane" (Ctrl-Shift-P if You don't see it), from the tabulators "Style", "Text", "Arrange" select "Style", then click on "Set as Default Style" at the bottom! Good luck

Answer (score -3):

you can go customize the fonts in draw io by going onto the right and go in change fonts and put a random number for a random font

Comment: To improve this answer and make it more useful, please attache some further steps / screenshots / etc.