# How to change arrow font size?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I would like to change the default font size for text on arrows.

Whenever I add text to an arrow its fontsize 11 which is far too small. Where can one set the default font size for arrow text? I do not want to change the fontsize for every single arrow:

[image]

Btw: This is not a duplicate of [How to change the default font in draw.io?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90871/how-to-change-the-default-font-in-draw-io), because this is about the font-size for arrows.

Comment: If the text is associated with a connector, select the connector, select the "text" panel in the right-hand format panel and adjust the font size. If this isn't the case, please add an image to show what you mean.

Comment: @David sry I think I didn't make clear enough, that I looking for a default setting, so that I don't have to adjust the fontsize for every single arrow. I have added a gif how I currently do it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again?

The current version 20.7.4 does have the behaviour you expect.

I drew this the same way you did and the `Second text` automatically had the larger font.
[image]

P.S. Awesome animated GIF by the way! :-)

**Update 24.01.2023**
Note that with version 21.0.0 the above behaviour will change. See [here](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/discussions/3312).